Controller Manager Not Available in ROS2 Humble
I am facing issue when using ros2_control for my robot in gazebo. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble. When i launch my launch file it gives me below error
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [44253]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher_gui-2]: process started with pid [44255]
[INFO] [rviz2-3]: process started with pid [44257]
[INFO] [gzserver-4]: process started with pid [44259]
[INFO] [gzclient-5]: process started with pid [44261]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-6]: process started with pid [44263]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [44265]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [WARN] [1714550826.328942901] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329177982] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329289725] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329320734] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329344479] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment castor_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329367736] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forearm_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329393507] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment hand_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329418719] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714550826.329442115] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[rviz2-3] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[joint_state_publisher_gui-2] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1714550826.770197287] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1714550826.770530073] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-6] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-6]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1714550826.772131984] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1714550826.773766092] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1714550826.774055368] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[joint_state_publisher_gui-2] [INFO] [1714550826.845186750] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[joint_state_publisher_gui-2] [INFO] [1714550826.851637697] [joint_state_publisher]: Centering
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1714550826.889815949] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1714550826.889898011] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1714550826.905062987] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[joint_state_publisher_gui-2] [INFO] [1714550826.952672453] [joint_state_publisher]: Centering
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1714550827.529843385] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1714550827.795961443] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [my_robot]
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.803448182] [joint_state_publisher_controller]: Going to publish joint [arm_base_forearm_joint]
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.803798916] [joint_state_publisher_controller]: Going to publish joint [forearm_hand_joint]
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.839450862] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.842340686] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.842395720] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.843207536] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/grim/ros2_ws/install/arm_bot_description/share/arm_bot_description/config/my_controllers.yaml
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.843411677] [gazebo_ros2_control]: after remapping 
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.846787655] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.848986067] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
[gzserver-4] [WARN] [1714550827.862844974] [gazebo_ros2_control]: The position_proportional_gain parameter was not defined, defaulting to: 0.1
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.863426110] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_right_wheel
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.863572005] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.863607763] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.863855694] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.863877204] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.864208035] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_left_wheel
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.864225425] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.864237647] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.864332838] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.864346527] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.864745800] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.865703580] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.865914147] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.865926159] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.865933283] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.865939429] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.866409450] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager ..
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.878933093] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.880055905] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager's next
[gzserver-4] [WARN] [1714550827.880263468] [gazebo_ros2_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.1 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[gzserver-4] [INFO] [1714550827.881606624] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loaded gazebo_ros2_control.
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 44263]
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1714550828.694060283] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1714550830.703203493] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1714550832.714023991] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1714550834.724531697] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1714550836.734831926] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 44265, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner diffbot_base_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].


This is my launch file in XML

<launch>

    <let name="urdf_path" 
         value="$(find-pkg-share arm_bot_description)/urdf/project.urdf.xacro"/>

    <let name="rviz_config_path" 
         value="$(find-pkg-share arm_bot_description)/rviz/boturdf_config.rviz"/>
    
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" exec="robot_state_publisher" >
            <param name="robot_description"
                   value="$(command 'xacro $(var urdf_path)')" />
    </node>
    
    <node pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" exec="joint_state_publisher_gui" />
    
    <node pkg="rviz2" exec="rviz2" output="screen" 
                      args="-d $(var rviz_config_path)"/>

    <include file="$(find-pkg-share gazebo_ros)/launch/gazebo.launch.py" >
  <arg name="world" value= "$(find-pkg-share my_robot_bringup)/worlds/test.world"/>
    </include>

    <node pkg="gazebo_ros" exec="spawn_entity.py" 
          args="-topic robot_description -entity my_robot" />
     

     <node pkg="controller_manager" exec="spawner" 
           args="diffbot_base_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager" />


</launch>

This is my yaml file for ros2_control
controller_manager:
 ros__parameters:
  update_rate: 10
  use_sim_time: true

  joint_state_broadcaster:
   type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

  diffbot_base_controller:
   type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

diffbot_base_controller:
 ros__parameters:
  publish_rate: 50.0
  odom_frame_id: odom
  base_frame_id: base_link
  left_wheel_names: ['base_left_wheel']
  right_wheel_names: ['base_right_wheel']
  wheel_separation: 0.45
  wheel_radius: 0.1
  use_stamped_vel: false
  enable_odom_tf: true

This is my CmakeList.txt file
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(arm_bot_description)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

install(
  DIRECTORY config urdf launch rviz 
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
)

ament_package()


Pls help me with this problem as i am unable to make any progress since last 5 days. Thanks a lot in advance for your help
Edit 1: When I try list hardware interfaces for my robot it shows the following
ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces 
Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_hardware_interfaces

Edit 2: Actually I have split my  urdf file into different files
This is for robot base
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro = "http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <!-- making variables using "xacro:property" -->
    <xacro:property name="base_length" value="0.6" />
    <xacro:property name="base_width" value="0.4" />
    <xacro:property name="base_height" value="0.2" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.1" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_length" value="0.05" />

    
    <link name="base_footprint"/>

    <link name="base_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
           <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}" />
    </geometry>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${base_height/2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <material name="blue" />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}" />
    </geometry>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${base_height/2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
      </collision>
      <xacro:box_inertia m="5.0" l="${2*base_length}" w="${2*base_width}" 
      h="${2*base_height}" xyz="0 0 ${base_height/2.0}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </link>

    <joint name="base_footprint"  type="fixed">
        <parent link = "base_link" />
        <child link = "base_footprint" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${-base_height/2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint> 

 
    <!-- making function for right and left wheels using "xacro:macro" -->
    <xacro:macro name = "wheel_link" params = "prefix" >
        <link name="${prefix}_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz ="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 0" />
                <material name="grey" />
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}" />
                </geometry>
                <origin xyz ="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <xacro:solid-cylinder_inertia m= "2.0" r= "${2*wheel_radius}"  h="${2*wheel_length}"
                     xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 0"/>
        </link>
    </xacro:macro>
    
    <!-- to make right wheel -->
    <xacro:wheel_link prefix = "right" />

    <!-- to make left wheel -->
    <xacro:wheel_link prefix = "left" />  
    
    <joint name="base_right_wheel"  type="continuous">
        <parent link = "base_link" />
        <child link = "right_wheel" />
        <origin xyz="${-base_length/3.0} ${-base_width*0.5625} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="base_left_wheel"  type="continuous">
        <parent link = "base_link" />
        <child link = "left_wheel" />
        <origin xyz="${-base_length/3.0} ${base_width*0.5625} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>    
    
    
    <joint name="base_castor_wheel"  type="fixed">
        <parent link = "base_link" />
        <child link = "castor_wheel" />
        <origin xyz="${base_length/3.0} 0 ${-base_height/4.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>    
    
    <link name="castor_wheel">
        <visual>
           <geometry>
               <sphere radius="${wheel_radius/2.0}" />
       </geometry>
       <origin xyz ="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 0" />
           <material name="grey" />
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${wheel_radius/2.0}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz ="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <xacro:solid-sphere_inertia m= "1.0" r= "${2*wheel_radius/2.0}" xyz= "0 0 0" rpy= "${pi/2.0} 0 0"/>
    </link>

    
 <!-- when using reference to specific link everything written within that block
    will only effect that link -->

    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="left_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="right_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="castor_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
        <mu1 value="0.1"/>
        <mu2 value="0.1"/>
    </gazebo>  

</robot>


This is for robot arm
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:property name="arm_base_length" value="0.1" />
    <xacro:property name="arm_base_width" value="0.1" />
    <xacro:property name="arm_base_height" value="0.02" />
    <xacro:property name="forearm_radius" value="0.02" />
    <xacro:property name="forearm_length" value="0.3" />
    <xacro:property name="hand_radius" value="0.02" />
    <xacro:property name="hand_length" value="0.3" />

    <link name="arm_base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${arm_base_length} ${arm_base_width} ${arm_base_height}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${arm_base_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name= "orange">
                <color rgba= "1.0 0.5 0 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${arm_base_length} ${arm_base_width} ${arm_base_height}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${arm_base_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz= "0 0 ${arm_base_height / 2.0}" rpy= "0 0 0"/>
        <mass value= "0.5" />
        <inertia ixx="${(0.5/12) * (arm_base_length * arm_base_length + arm_base_height * arm_base_height)}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                     iyy = "${(0.5/12) * (arm_base_length * arm_base_length + arm_base_width * arm_base_width)}" iyz="0"  
                 izz="${(0.5/12) * (arm_base_height * arm_base_height + arm_base_width * arm_base_width)}" />
        </inertial>
    </link>


    <link name="forearm_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${forearm_radius}" length="${forearm_length}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 ${forearm_length / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <material name="yellow" >
            <color rgba= "1.0 1.0 0 1" />
        </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="${forearm_radius}" length="${forearm_length}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${forearm_length / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz= "0 0 ${forearm_length / 2.0}" rpy= "0 0 0"/>
        <mass value= "0.3" />
        <inertia ixx="${(0.3/12) * (3 * forearm_radius * forearm_radius + forearm_length * forearm_length)}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                     iyy = "${(0.3/12) * (3 * forearm_radius * forearm_radius + forearm_length * forearm_length)}" iyz="0"  
                 izz="${(0.3/2) * (forearm_radius * forearm_radius)}" />
        </inertial>
    </link>


    <link name="hand_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${hand_radius}" length="${hand_length}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 ${hand_length / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <material name="orange" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="${hand_radius}" length="${hand_length}" />
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${hand_length / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz= "0 0 ${hand_length / 2.0}" rpy= "0 0 0"/>
        <mass value= "0.3" />
        <inertia ixx="${(0.3/12) * (3 * hand_radius * hand_radius + hand_length * hand_length)}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                     iyy = "${(0.3/12) * (3 * hand_radius * hand_radius + hand_length * hand_length)}" iyz="0"  
                 izz="${(0.3/2) * (hand_radius * hand_radius)}" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    
    <joint name="arm_base_forearm_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="arm_base_link" />
        <child link="forearm_link" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${arm_base_height}" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit lower="0" upper="${pi/2}" effort="100" velocity="100" />
        <dynamics friction="0.05" damping="0.1"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="forearm_hand_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="forearm_link" />
        <child link="hand_link" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${forearm_length}" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit lower="0" upper="${pi/2}" effort="100" velocity="100" />
        <dynamics friction="0.05" damping="0.1"/>
    </joint>

    
    <gazebo reference="arm_base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="forearm_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="hand_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    </gazebo>

</robot>

This is my ros2 control file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="arm_bot" xmlns:xacro = "http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="base_right_wheel">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>

        <joint name="base_left_wheel">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
            <parameters>$(find arm_bot_description)/config/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>


</robot>


This is my file that includes all urdf file into one
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="arm_bot" xmlns:xacro = "http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

 <!-- is the main project file that includes other files -->

    <xacro:include filename="arm.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="arm_gazebo.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="common_properties.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="mobile_base.xacro"/>
    <!-- <xacro:include filename="mobile_base_gazebo.xacro"/> -->
    <xacro:include filename="mobile_base_ros2_control.xacro"/>
    

    <joint name="base_arm_joint"  type="fixed">
        <parent link = "base_link" />
        <child link = "arm_base_link" />
        <origin xyz="${base_length/4.0} 0 ${base_height}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

</robot>



I have tried everything recommended in this post Controller manager not available but still I am unable to make any progress
Edit 3: I am able to run demo ros2_control example2
ros2 launch ros2_control_demo_example_2 diffbot.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/grim/.ros/log/2024-05-10-12-18-08-455798-team1691-6110
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-1]: process started with pid [6112]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [6114]
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [6116]
[robot_state_publisher-2] [WARN] [1715323688.829160895] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1715323688.829310653] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1715323688.829383926] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_frontal_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1715323688.829402576] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_rear_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1715323688.829419759] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1715323688.829437361] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.861773691] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.862836949] [controller_manager]: update rate is 10 Hz
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.863186898] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.865100930] [controller_manager]: Received robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.865410296] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'DiffBot' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.866763223] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'DiffBot' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.867270334] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'DiffBot'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.867491969] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'DiffBot' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.867515927] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'DiffBot'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.867529688] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'DiffBot' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.867565032] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Activating ...please wait...
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.867579770] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Successfully activated!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.867592692] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'DiffBot'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.963475838] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.963561614] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.963590671] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Writing...
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.963606388] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.963622593] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323688.963661220] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Joints successfully written!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.063425295] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.063518755] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1715323689.288633758] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.289929336] [controller_manager]: ***Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'***
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.290157885] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.563571853] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Writing...
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.563586662] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.563601400] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.563615719] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Joints successfully written!
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1715323689.565382435] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: ***Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster***
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.663422209] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323689.663487729] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.363490717] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Writing...
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.363500915] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.363510345] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.363519356] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Joints successfully written!
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1715323690.387716410] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Loaded diffbot_base_controller
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.388940110] [controller_manager]: ***Configuring controller 'diffbot_base_controller***'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.463398429] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.463454379] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.663810161] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Writing...
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.663828881] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.663845924] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got command 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.663860383] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Joints successfully written!
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1715323690.665237893] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: ***Configured and activated diffbot_base_controller***
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.763395446] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'left_wheel_joint'!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715323690.763453211] [DiffBotSystemHardware]: Got position state 0.00000 and velocity state 0.00000 for 'right_wheel_joint'!



Somebody pls help me as I am completely clueless about this behaviour

Can you launch the examples from gazebo_ros2_control_demos package?

Could you please share the urdf file? I think that the error is generated by some wrong configuration of the plug-in.

Please add the full log to your initial question.

@ChristophFroehlich can u pls elaborate what do u exactly mean by your question

you just shared a single line of your console output. But this is not root problem, the controller manager/gazebo_ros2_control had a problem already earlier.

@ChristophFroehlich this is all i get in my terminal when i run my launch file

I speak of the gazebo_ros2_control_demos package you posted in the comments. If this one is not working already, we don't have to look at your custom robot.

@ChristophFroehlich I added the logs of ros2_control demos as u suggested

what have you changed that the example_2 works now? But please check the gazebo_ros2_control_demos as I've written above. example_2 does not include gazebo_ros2_control.

@ChristophFroehlich as u suggest I tried gazebo_ros2_control demos package and it is running perfectly.
